# RadioListTile is not working with setstate

Tags: flutter

What is working when i click on radio button it is not changing

```
class OnBoardingCheckBoxWithActionWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  String label;
  Function onClick;
  OnBoardingCheckBoxWithActionWidget(this.label, {this.onClick});
  @override
  _OnBoardingCheckBoxWithActionWidgetState createState() =>
      _OnBoardingCheckBoxWithActionWidgetState();
}

class _OnBoardingCheckBoxWithActionWidgetState
    extends State<OnBoardingCheckBoxWithActionWidget> {
  bool checked = true;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: RadioListTile(
          value: checked,
          groupValue: checked,
          toggleable: true,
          title: Text("${widget.label}"),
          onChanged: (val) {
            if (widget.onClick != null) {
              widget.onClick(val);
            }
            setState(() {
              print("$checked");
              checked = !checked;
              print("$checked");
            });
          },
        ),
      ),
    ); // Card(child: Row(children: [Expanded(child: RadioListTile())],),);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to change some value from your Parent Stateful widget.

Try changing your current widget like

```
class OnBoardingCheckBoxWithActionWidget
    extends StatelessWidget {
  String label;
  Function onClick;
  var groupValue;
  var buttonValue;

  OnBoardingCheckBoxWithActionWidget(this.label, {this.onClick, this.groupValue,, this.buttonValue});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: RadioListTile(
          value: buttonValue,
          groupValue: groupValue,
          toggleable: true,
          title: Text("${this.label}"),
          onChanged: (val) {
            if (this.onClick != null) {
              this.onClick(val);
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    ); // Card(child: Row(children: [Expanded(child: RadioListTile())],),);
  }
}
```

And then call it like

```
   OnBoardingCheckBoxWithActionWidget("Button1", onClick: (value){ 
    setState((){
     ///Your Other Code
     if(value){
      groupValue = 'button1';
     }
    }); 
   }, 
   groupValue: someGroupValueVariableInState, buttonValue: 'button1')
```

Note that, the groupValue and buttonValue variables will always be some other variables other than booleans. When groupValue == buttonValue, the corresponding button will automatically marked as checked.

Comment: what about variable u used "checked"?

Comment: @Midhilaj My Bad, that was `buttonValue`, I've edited my answer.